# Centos 6 - Nginx - [emerg] socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (105: No buffer space available)

Tags: nginx

I tried to restart nginx by doing:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

However I receive this error message:

```
nginx: [emerg] socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (105: No buffer space available)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My server has been working fine until I did that and now my website won't load

Now every few pages I receive:

```
Error!
The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.
```

Would you guys be able to suggest a fix?

Edit - This is on a Centos 6 VPS

Comment: Please describe the operating system and hardware in use.

Comment: It's a centos 6 VPS, not sure about hardware

Comment: Then describe the VPS?

Comment: It's package 3 on here - http://volumedrive.com/vdrive/?a=vps

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be from kernel+nginx interaction or some resource limitation on your VPS.

Try to add this to your config:

**1.** To decrease the number of opened sockets, turning off keepalive:

`keepalive_timeout  0;`

**2.** Decrease the size of tcp buffers (listen-sockets):

`listen  80 default rcvbuf=8k  sndbuf=32k;`

Please also provide information from:

`cat /proc/user_beancounters`